# How can I price of 100 EUR in RON on 1st of every month back to 4 years

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

I would like to see the difference between 450 RON and 100EUR converted to RON on 1st of every month back to 4 years.
possibly with a cumulated chart...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we generate our dates:

```
dates = Flatten@
  Table[DateObject[{year, month, 1}], {year, 2015, 2019}, {month, 1, 12}]
```

then we can use `CurrencyConvert`:

```
values = Table[
  CurrencyConvert[Quantity[100, "Euros"], "RomanianLei", d], {d, dates}]
```

And now we can display it, for instance like this, drawing a line at 450 lei:

```
DateListPlot[Thread[{dates, values}], FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
 Epilog :> {Dotted, Red, Line[{{{2015, 1, 1}, 450}, {{2019, 12, 1}, 450}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: How can we get the total of the difference between 100 Eur in ROn and 450. Something like. values.map{|x|x-450}.sum (that was ruby, but you get the idea.)?

Comment: `Total[values - Quantity[450, "RomanianLei"]]`, which results in `Quantity[469.35, "RomanianLei"]`